# Test cases failed by running all but passed by running one by one

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I built a test suite contains 15 Test cases. When I ran each Test case one by one, they all passed. But when I ran all of them in a time, only 7 first testcases passed, the rest failed all. And the error all showed that Visual Studio was unable to find the web element (I used `XPath`).

I put `thread.sleep()` to code so that each test case could have time to detect elements, but this didn't work also.

I'm sure that all the `XPath` were correct, please anyone could give me any ideas?

Comment: Check for dependency (what are shared between all of the test cases) and debug the code (run and see what exact errors you are getting)

Comment: how are your test cases structured? When you run your test cases one by one, does that mean you open and close browser for each one of them? when you run your test cases together, does that mean you execute your test cases interactively, e.g. actions resulted from one test have affects on other tests?

Comment: Thanks @kurakura88. 
I built testcases based on Page Object Modal, all the test cases are inheritance from a General Class, and this class is inheritance from a Base Test Method that contains Test Initialize and Test Cleanup. So do these relationships cause the issue?
About the error, as I said they always show that it was unable to find the web elements, I debugged repeatly for several times by replacing the XPath with 'By.Id' or 'By.Name' but all the solutions didn't work at all. 
Really stuck in this situation.

Comment: @YuZhang, I use a base test method class that contains TestInitialize (Open browser) and TestCleanup (Clear cookies, delete session, and close browser). That mean each test case is independence and can be executed separately without getting effects from any other ones' actions.

Comment: Could have been the web driver is not setup/ cleaned up properly for the next test after the clean up. I would suggest you to debug and share the code, otherwise, it is all just suggestion. We won't be able to provide correct solution.

Comment: Based on your comments, I really found the reason. Actually, testcases 7 was failed because the assert, the actual message displayed in app was not equal with expected message. So the process stopped and the command logout below it could not execute. Thus, the next testcase could not find the login element.
Really thank you!!